# php - detect protected method and avoid fatal error

Tags: php, oop, reflection, methods, properties

I have to get properties from multiple classes stored in one directory.

I have no problems collecting protected and public properties.

I'm after public only, so all's fine up to now.

What I do:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($foo);
$props   = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC | ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED);
foreach ($props as $prop) {
    print $prop->getName() . "\n";
}
```

However, some classes do have protected methods, e.g. :

```
class Foo {
    public    $foo  = 1;
    protected $bar  = 2;
    private   $baz  = 3;

    protected function __construct()
    {

    }
}
```

Once I hit such a class, I get a fatal error, which stalls mys efforts:

```
Fatal error: Call to protected Foo::__construct() from context 'View' in [path/goes/here]
```

What is the best way around it? (if there is one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$foo = new Foo();
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($foo);
```

to

```
$reflect = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
```

If you actually want to create a new instance, look at the `newInstanceWithoutConstructor` function

Answer (score 0):

If you use `protected` or `private` then your constructor will not be accessible from outside of the class.

Calling `$foo = new Foo();` will throw an error.

```
$reflect = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
echo $reflect->getName();// output Foo
```